# How can I retrieve a MS SQL Express Database from a non-booting computer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, sql-server

A client has a very important database that has not been backed up in 6 months. The PC has promptly failed. The Windows directory is corrupt, and the computer will not boot.

It had a Microsoft SQL Server Express 2005 database on it. I have access to the hard drive by booting in with an Ubuntu Live CD, but I am not sure if I can find the database. I am not sure what I am looking for, or where to look either. The dead machine had Windows XP on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are searching for something usualy stored like this

```
Folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data

Filenames:

<DBNAME>.mdf
<DBNAME>_log.ldf
```

probably existing backups are stored usualy here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\<anyname>.bak
```

Comment: These are the default locations, but I'd search the entire hard drive for .MDF and .LDF files just-in-case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data